# QML: Do not use 'eval' (M23)

Tags: javascript, eval, qml

Why do I get this message when using the `eval()` function inside JS, in QML?

How else could I refer to an object `text_123` when I know only it's ID : the "123" ?

Answer (score -1):

every object belongs to a parent object.

in websites the root element is window.

if you defined a global object you could do:

`window["text_" + 123]`

in order to access that variable.

Comment: because there is no global object in QML, and because ID is not a real property.